# RTD Server C#: Getting "N/A" in deployment

Tags: c#, excel, excel-2007, rtd

I have created Excel RTD Server, after all implementation completion in debug mode, I am able to run RTD and it is working fine. But when I get the dll in release mode and take it to another system, and register using "regasm.exe" and also provided complete DCOM user access with "everyone" but still using =RTD(), gives me error as #N/A.

I am expecting something I am doing in deployment.

I am stuck here, please help me out.

Thanks

Comment: Debug Tip: print to a log file after every line.

Comment: Hi Jake, I have debug it,it  is getting register properly and I can find it i automation list of excel, but while using it is not excel not invoking startserver(), connectdata() of RTD function

Answer (score 3):

I had similar issue, in my case the office installed on the machine was 64-bit, therefor i had to register the RTD dll using the 64-bit regasm.exe.

Take a look here:
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/exceldev/thread/7a9e865e-5138-45c0-8f31-ddc148509dbe

good luck.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem too and it turned out that while in debug mode, VS was able to see my RTDServer, in deploy, windows couldn't because I hadn't explicitly instructed the setup project to do so. To register the `rtdsrver.dll` as part of a setup project you can do the following:

- right click on the setup project: view -> filesystem
- in the file system viewer, select the system folder
- select your rtdserver.dll and view it's properties
- set the `Register` field to `vsdraCOM`
- Redeploy

Now, excel should be able to see your server assembly in deploy.